# Converting survey results from a 1-4 scale average to a 1-5 scale average

Tags: survey-weights

I'm completely new at analyzing survey answers, and it will be great if anybody can help me out here with conversion technique. Survey participants were provided answer choices on a ranking scale of 1-4 and we got the average. 
We're trying to change the ranking scale to 1-5. I understand that there are different schools of thoughts that participants would have responded differently if they'd been given a different range of scale, but it needs to be converted.

I keep thinking that there must be a formula that can be applied to this, but I cannot come up with it. For instance, if average score is 3.4, what kind of arithmetic formula should I use to get an average score on the 1-5 scale?

Any insight will be greatly appreciated & thank you so much!

Comment: You can't do arithmetic formulas on survey scales, unless somehow you know that the scales are linear. why would they be linear though? Why do you want to re-scale?

Comment: @NickCox - I came across the posting! And I tried to wrap around my head but I wasn't clear on whether I can still apply the same formula in my case. You see, I'm pretty clueless here. new=0.5 (1+old) Will truly appreciate it if you could provide the similar formula in this case. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @Aksakal - Honestly, I haven't thought about that. Would you mind elaborating how it can be problematic?

Comment: The posting covers the principles only, but the details are just algebra,  or arithmetic. For your particular numbers, (1) Subtract 1. Now your numbers range 0 to 3. (2) Multiply by 4/3. Now your numbers range 0 to 4. (3) Add 1. @NuclAcc already gave this answer.

Comment: There is a big difference between "can/can't" and "should/shouldn't". No one presumably supposes that if given a scale 1 to 5 any recipient would say "I prefer to think 1,2,3,4 and I really want to say 2, but if you insist on that scale my answer is 7/3." But if there is a context in which e.g. calculating mean scores for questions is desired and makes sense, then what other solution is there (other than saying "That can't be done; measurements were taken on a different scale", a defensible view but not necessarily a practical one)?

Comment: So, yes, non-integer equivalents are arbitrary and artificial (and we can't even be sure that everyone who voted 1 on one scale would vote 1 on the other, with a similar comment for top grades). .

Comment: @NickCox, what's missing is "why?" what's the purpose? also your conversion does not convert integer to integer, your output is fractional

Comment: @Aksakal That's not missing. Average scores are mentioned three times and to me wanting averages is the most obvious single reason for this. The OP or anybody else who ever wants this should chime in with other reasons. (I am presupposing that "Don't mix scales without a superlatively good reason for doing that" is good advice that somebody should have heeded.)

Comment: @SBiel, was there a neutral rank in your 4 level scale? For instance, often you're asked "rate your experience with a service," then the choices are 1-poor, 2-neither and 3-good. Here, 2 is neutral. In 4 level scale you may have "poor", "average", "good" and "very good", in which case 2 should translate to 3 in 5 level scale, not to 2.5

Comment: @NickCox without knowing whether 4 level scale is symmetric or has neutral grade, the arithmetic translation cannot be suggested in my opinion even if the average is considered. if you have asymmetric 4 level scale and 5 level scale is a typical symmetric Likert scale, then arithmetic translation will be biased

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for providing the formula, although it's laden with arbitrariness. Exactly needed some practicality here.

Comment: @Arksakal, Thank you for your elaboration - it helps me to think more critically. Unfortunately the 4 level scale didn't include a neutral answer choice. i.e., 4- Strongly Agree, 3- Agree, 2-Disagree, 1- Strongly Disagree. It was designed by a predecessor, and now we're trying to include a neutral grade to capture a more accurate portrait.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you probably shouldn't... BUT if you must. 1.33(x - 1) + 1 Should do it. To break that down,

1. you take the number of response options on the old scale -1 to address your minimum being 1 In your case 3
2. put that in the denominator and the new scale -1 in the numerator to address your minimum being 1. In your case 4.
3. That should leave you with 4/3 = 1.33 (your scaling coefficient. Get the scale down to 0 by subtracting 1 from your variable. This is to address the fact that your minimum is 1 (again).
4. Multiply by the scaling coefficient.
5. Add the one back unless you want your lowest point to be 0 on a 0-4 scale.

Hope that helps clarify

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: Expanded on it. Hopefully it makes a little more sense now. Maybe I need to take the tour to figure out why an answer should be posted as a comment rather than an answer. I'll get on that.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, you won't be able to comment until your reputation is >50. This does help, & turns it into more of an 'answer'.